# How to align a Date/Time in a field?

Tags: time, alignment, wpf

I have some issues about choosing how to align a Date/time data type in a field. Which is the best way to align this type of date and why? Right or left?
P.S We use WPF.

[------25.03.2015] or [25.03.2015------]

Thank you :)

Comment: This depends on what's around this element. Can you show us a page design so we can give you an informed answer?

Comment: I agree with Majo0od - this is a design question that is very context-sensitive. What else is on the page, is this in a column of data or is the display more like a row? What is the user trying to do: are they scanning for information, or analyzing a report? Even what nationality are your users? etc.

Comment: This field is in a details panel - there are field for Name, Code, Multiline text and others. Clicking on this Date field appears a Calendar :) The users are from from a lot of countries - generally Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to put that in the right side of the date, because this counts as an extra detail about an update, the date is more important than the time, so keep the date on left.

You can also seperate the date and time by using "at".
**25/03/2015 at 11:34:21**